# 74LS74N did not work exactly as I expected

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

[image]

[image]

74LS74-Dual DFF module driven both Q and Q' to high even when I turn on Preset or Clear pin.
What wrong?

Comment: Does it operate in the "normal" configuration (i.e. preset and clear both high)?

Comment: No, both Q Q' high every time.

Comment: You are likely not giving it voltages the chip expects to work properly. Please draw a schematic, we can't see with 100% certainty how you have connected everything.

Comment: Oh god, you are right, I'm not giving its voltage the chip expects. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank everybody in this thread. I fixed it by throwing away 4 LEDs at inputs (which steals my voltage for IC), then I added some RES at the output LEDs (which reduces current so that IC can supply effectively for LEDs.
Now I have learnt that what I draw and what I simulate on Proteus does not mean that it is right when it comes to the real circuit-many weird things about choosing RES.
Here is my sexy 3 bit binary counter: https://youtu.be/gYBrn3IssQU

Answer (score 1):

Likely the input voltages are wrong due to LEDs in parallel with the input.